# chartist not displaying an image in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I've been trying to use the Chartist package available on GitHub

https://github.com/yutannihilation/chartist

similar to the example, I ran the following:

```
devtools::install_github("yutannihilation/chartist")
library(chartist)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(metricsgraphics)

set.seed(324)
data <- data.frame(
  day = paste("day", 1:10),
  A   = runif(10, 0, 10),
  B   = runif(10, 0, 10),
  C   = runif(10, 0, 10)
)
```

I then went to plot the data:

```
chartist(data, day)
```

And nothing shows up.  Just blank.

I've tried changing around the syntax a lot and still can't get anything to show up.   Has anyone else tried to use this package and had any luck?

Answer (score 0):

What's your R.version? Do all of the packages load correctly? What OS are you using? Are you using R studio?

On my laptop (info below) your code ran and produced the attached image.

```
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin13.4.0                
system         x86_64, darwin13.4.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.2                         
year           2014                        
month          10                          
day            31                          
svn rev        66913                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
nickname       Pumpkin Helmet
```

[image]

Comment: when i run the version, everything looks the same except:  

platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32 
system         x86_64, mingw32

Comment: do you think it could be with viewing svgs?   it's weird because htmlwidgets seems to work just fine

Comment: are you using R studio, the command line or the R GUI (or other?)? I'm not sure why you can't see the image. Maybe try to export / save it?